# Please recommend a book re: Amazon AWS and EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, cloud

Starting to use AWS, setting up a few permanent instances, several temporary ones, maybe some storage, monitoring, DNS - the works.

I'm looking for a book geared towards the experienced technical used who is new to AWS in general, especially EC2. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AWS has undergone lots of revisions so you'll find the [AWS website](http://aws.amazon.com/) will be the best place to get the latest info. If you do want a hard copy reference though you could try "[Host Your Web Site In The Cloud: Amazon Web Services Made Easy: Amazon EC2 Made Easy](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0980576830)" by Jeff Barr. I'd recommend checking the product description, taking advantage of the table of contents, and reading some of the sample pages to see if it has the kind of content you're looking for. I find with introductory books how suitable they are depends a lot on your previous knowledge.